# Quick jump to tmux session

Tags: tmux, session

Is there actually any way / plugin to be able to quickly jump to a session?

Currently I `<leader>s` to open the session-list page and then I select the one I want.

And if I have a session that I want to jump to a lot, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You could use `byobu`. It is built on the top of `tmux` and its key-bindings  are more sensible.

Answer (score 3):

You are likely looking for 'switch-client' command

```
switchc -t <session name|number>
```

example

```
# create a named session
tmux new -s 'main_session'

# to switch to it you would use the command
switchc -t 'main_session'
```

To the session which you jump a lot, if you name it the same every time then you can bind a key for it. In your ~/.tmux.conf file add

```
bind  J  switchc -t 'main_session'
```

Other great options would be :

```
# last session used, great for toggling between two sessions
# tmux binds this command to 'L' by default
switchc -l

# to rotate through all sessions
switchc -n

# to go to a named session
command-prompt -p 'switch to session : ' 'switchc -t %1'
```

You could add these bindings to your ~/.tmux.conf

```
# rotate through sessions
bind  R  switchc -n

# go to a session by name
bind  S  command-prompt -p 'Session name : ' 'switchc -t %1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this great blob post https://waylonwalker.com/tmux-fzf-session-jump/ that configures a key (`Ctrl-J` in the examples below) to pop up a window to select a session to switch to. It uses [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) to interactively search through all available sessions:

```
bind C-j new-window -n "session-switcher" "\
    tmux list-sessions -F '#{?session_attached,,#{session_name}}' |\
    sed '/^$/d' |\
    fzf --reverse --header jump-to-session --preview 'tmux capture-pane -pt {}'  |\
    xargs tmux switch-client -t"
```

With tmux version 3.2 and later it's also possible to use command `display-popup` to create a pop-up window:

```
bind C-j display-popup -E "\
    tmux list-sessions -F '#{?session_attached,,#{session_name}}' |\
    sed '/^$/d' |\
    fzf --reverse --header jump-to-session --preview 'tmux capture-pane -pt {}'  |\
    xargs tmux switch-client -t"
```